# Regex allow letters only and option for one space only

Tags: regex

I have a regex that check if the input has only a-z and A-Z and spaces.

this is my expretion

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

I am trying to allow a-z A-Z and if the user type sapce it will be only one space.

Exapmle:

`ACB` => vaild

`adsbc aDb` => vaild

`adbc def gh` => not vaild

What do I need to change in my regex?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: A `regex` delimiter (`/`) must be placed at the end of the `regex` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]*[ ]?[A-Za-z]*$
```

To keep things simple, you want to match either zero or one space, either at the start, in the middle, or at the end, of the entire string.  The above regex expresses this.

### Demo

We could also solve this using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.* .* )[A-Za-z ]*$
```

This uses an assertion that, from the beginning of the string, two spaces do not appear anywhere.  However, I would expect the first solution to perform better.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z]*(\s[a-zA-Z]*)?$
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/EizIcj/1)

Comment: @MrLord It's missing a couple of edge cases, test it yourself.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right, I didn't account for these